# Opencv multiply scalar and matrix

Tags: opencv, matrix, scale, multiplication, scalar

I have been trying to achieve something which should pretty trivial and is trivial in *Matlab*.

Using methods of OpenCV, I want to simply achieve something such as:

```cpp
cv::Mat sample = [4 5 6; 4 2 5; 1 4 2];      
sample = 5*sample;
```

After which sample should just be:

```cpp
[20 25 30; 20 10 25; 5 20 10]
```

I have tried `scaleAdd`, `Mul`, `Multiply` and neither allow a scalar multiplier and require a matrix of the same "size and type". In this scenario I could create a Matrix of Ones and then use the scale parameter but that seems so very extraneous

Any direct simple method would be great!

Comment: Shouldn't `24` be `25` instead??? :P

Comment: What language is the code in?

Answer (score 24):

OpenCV does in fact support multiplication by a scalar value with overloaded `operator*`. You might need to initialize the matrix correctly, though.

```cpp
float data[] = {1 ,2, 3,
                4, 5, 6,
                7, 8, 9};
cv::Mat m(3, 3, CV_32FC1, data);
m = 3*m;  // This works just fine
```

If you are mainly interested in mathematical operations, `cv::Matx` is a little easier to work with:

```cpp
cv::Matx33f mx(1,2,3,
               4,5,6,
               7,8,9);
mx *= 4;  // This works too
```

Comment: This function only works for single channeled images. This therefore does not work generally. You would have to split all the channels first and then recombine then, eg  //(3) Split the RGB image
 vector<Mat> imgPlanes(3);
 split(matImage, imgPlanes);
 Mat matImageK = imgPlanes[0];

Comment: is there no `/` operator?

Answer (score 5):

For java there is no operator overloading, but the Mat object provides the functionality with a convertTo method.

```
Mat dst= new Mat(src.rows(),src.cols(),src.type());
src.convertTo(dst,-1,scale,offset);
```

[Doc on this method is here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a3f356665bb0ca452e7d7723ccac9a810)

Answer (score 3):

For big Mats you should use [forEach](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a952ef1a85d70a510240cb645a90efc0d).

If C++11 is available:

```
m.forEach<double>([&](double& element, const int position[]) -> void
{
element *= 5;
}
);
```

Comment: why should this be better than using the builtin matrix-scalar multiplication or cv::multiply?

Answer (score 1):

something like this.

```
Mat m = (Mat_<float>(3, 3)<<
                    1, 2, 3,
                    4, 5, 6,
                    7, 8, 9)*5;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Mat A = //data;//source Matrix
Mat B;//destination Matrix
Scalar alpha = new Scalar(5)//factor
Core.multiply(A,alpha,b);
```